# How do set a Text from String?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on this subtitle system. And the way I have it set up is, I'm taking an array of strings, looping over them, then I'm trying to assign them to a text element. But that doesn't seem to be possible.

```
public class SubtitleManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] _Subtitles;
    public Text _Text;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        foreach(string subtitle in _Subtitles)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SubtitleCoroutine());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SubtitleCoroutine()
    {
        _Text=_Subtitles;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    }
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things:

1. You need to access the text property of the Text class to be able to pass on the string
2. You need to select an element from your string array, since Text.text only accepts strings not string arrays
3. You need to start the loop inside of the corutine so that the texts are displayed sequentially

```csharp
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SubtitleCoroutine());
    }

    IEnumerator SubtitleCoroutine()
    {
        foreach(string subtitle in _Subtitles)
        {
            _Text.text=subtitle;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.
I called the coroutine in the start instead of the update so it's only called once.

Comment: oops, missed that

Answer (score 2):

Acording to the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) you should be able to set it using `_Text.text = _Subtitles;`

Comment: I just tried it, and it says implicity convert type string[] to string

Comment: Oh I just noticed you're actually assigning _Subtitles instead of a single instance (```subtitle```). Try to put for loop into IEnumerator and assign each instance separately.

Answer (score 0):

the method text is only a string but _Subtitles is an array of strings.
You need to build a  single string with all element of _Subtitles.

Answer (score 0):

```
_Text.text = subtitle[0];
```

You can replace the number zero with any index in your array.